# Why does this ruby case statement give an unexpected result?

Tags: ruby

Why does the following ruby code return ""  instead of "Code is empty"?

```
code = ""
case code
when code.empty?
  "Code is empty"
else
  code
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your code is comparing `code` to `code.empty?`, i.e., the result of `code == code.empty?`, which is false.  A string can degrade to a boolean, but the explicit equality of `'' == true` will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `code.empty?` is a method call that calls the method `empty?` which returns the value `true`. The `true` value is then compared to the `code` variable using the expression `true === code`, which is false, so it executes the `else` block of code.

This is probably what you want instead:

```
case code
when ""
  "Code is empty"
else
  code
end
```

A simpler way to do it is by using the ternary operator:

```
code.empty? ? "Code is empty" : code
```